# Hide on body click exept item id = something

Tags: javascript

How do I hide the menu except if the user clicked on element with ID = 'menubutton'?

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    $('#menu').hide();
    });
```

Comment: *menu*, which menu ? please explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the not() selector

```
$('body :not(#menubutton)').click(function(event) {
    $('#menu').hide();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: This is *really* inefficient. It sets up a click handler on literally every node in the DOM, except for the `#menubutton` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `target` element.

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    // If the element clicked doesn't have the id "menubutton"
    if ( $(event.target).attr( 'id' ) !== 'menubutton' ) {
        $('#menu').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    // don't hide if the clicked element was #menubutton,
    // or any element within #menubotton
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#menubutton').length) {
        $('#menu').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body :not(div #menubutton)').click(function(event) {
   $('#menu').hide();
});
```

[jQuery Not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

The selector for not() might need some changes for your case

Comment: This won't select anything. It currently matches all `body` tags that don't match the provided selector - and since the `body` tag will never be within another div, it effectively does nothing.